# raise ValueError('Cannot set a frame with no defined index ' ValueError:

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm getting the following error for my code

> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 2519, in **setitem**
>       self._set_item(key, value)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 2584, in _set_item
>       self._ensure_valid_index(value)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 2566, in _ensure_valid_index
>       raise ValueError('Cannot set a frame with no defined index '
>
> ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that
>   cannot be converted to a Series

and since I'm still learning I'm having problems fixing it... What should I do?

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tweets_data_path="C:/Users/prono/.spyder-py3/twitter_data.txt"

tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue

print(len(tweets_data))

tweets = pd.DataFrame()

tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data)
tweets['lang'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['lang'], tweets_data)
tweets['country'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['country'] if tweet['place'] != None else None, tweets_data)

tweets_by_lang = tweets['lang'].value_counts()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=15)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=10)
ax.set_xlabel('Languages', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of tweets' , fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Top 5 languages', fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
tweets_by_lang[:5].plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color='red')

tweets_by_country = tweets['country'].value_counts()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=15)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=10)
ax.set_xlabel('Countries', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of tweets' , fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Top 5 countries', fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
tweets_by_country[:5].plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color='blue')
```

Comment: What does the data within twitter_data.txt look like?

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you share the data you are using, i.e. "twitter_data.txt"., perhaps via DropBox or GitHub. If that file is big, consider including just the first ~100 lines, enough to reproduce the error you are getting struck on. I'd guess that you are passing an empty array to your DataFrame.

Comment: also, on the side, what you did is fine, but in `functools`, the `attrgetter` function is intended for exactly this purpose: `map(attrgetter('text'), tweets_data`. just fyi.... would simplify a couple of your lines at least...

Comment: and: what does your print of `len(tweets_data)` print out? and what line is the error on? (you only showed the lower part of the traceback)?

Comment: also: after the failure, you can do `import pdb; pdb.pm()` and drop into the code where it failed, walk up the stack, and see exactly what the data looked like when it was complaining....